# Java String Match returning false even if its true

Tags: java, regex

**temp.matches** this regular expression is returning false even though there is proper matching expression (**SOUTH, NORTH,** )

temp value after execution **SOUTH, NORTH,**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class DirReduction {

    public static String[] dirReduc(String[] arr) {

        boolean check=false;
        String inputToString =Arrays.toString(arr);
        String str1 = inputToString.replace("]", ", ").replace("[", ""),temp;
        do {
            temp=str1.replaceAll("NORTH, SOUTH, " , "").replaceAll("SOUTH, NORTH, " , "").replaceAll("EAST, WEST, " , "").replaceAll("WEST, EAST, " , "");
            check = temp.matches(".*\\b(NORTH, SOUTH, |SOUTH, NORTH, |EAST, WEST, |WEST, EAST, )\\b.*");
            System.out.println(temp);
            str1=temp;
        }while(check);

        String[] splitArray = str1.split(", ");
        String[] fi =new String[splitArray.length];
        int i=0;
        for(String item:splitArray) {
            fi[i++]=item;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fi));
        return fi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = new String[] { "NORTH","SOUTH","SOUTH","EAST","WEST","NORTH"};
        dirReduc(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what the println(temp) is showing on console.

Comment: Please explain what you are doing, and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/directions-reduction      I was trying this problem but after the first set of replacement, temp will have "SOUTH, NORTH, " value, but regular expression is failing to identify it

Comment: If `temp` holds `"SOUTH, NORTH, "` then there is no match for `\\b` in `)\\b.*` because it is trying to match place between that last space and end of string which is no word boundary so match fails.

Comment: Like @Pshemo  says, the _last_ word boundary will not match a place between a `<space>` \b here `<end of string>` since both are non-word context. Also, it appears `temp=str1.replaceAll("NORTH, SOUTH, " , "").replaceAll("SOUTH, NORTH, " , "").replaceAll("EAST, WEST, " , "").replaceAll("WEST, EAST, " , "");` will always replace anything you're trying to match anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your replaceAll statement does not replace anything. Your input string does not have spaces after the comma, but your search mask has a space. So nothing will be found to be replaced.

Comment: first round of replace all is working as expected but temp.matches is returing fasle even though there is excat same string.